# Update a column in one csv based on another csv based on ID number

Tags: python, csv

I have 2 CSVs that contain data like this (except hundreds of students):

Original.csv:

| ID | First | Last | Homeroom | Grade | Address | Phone | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | Fred | Flinstone | Betty | 2 | 1 Main Street | 555-1212 | Anytown |
| 22 | Barney | Rubble | Wilma | 4 | 11 Slate Street | 555-1111 | Bedrock |

and

Update.csv:

| ID | First | Last | Homeroom | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | Fred | Flinstone | Smith | 2 |
| 22 | Barney | Rubble | Jones | 4 |

I need to update the first CSV or create a new CSV with the Homeroom updated from Update.csv so the resulting file contains all of Original.csv columns and data but updates the Homeroom.

Result.csv:

| ID | First | Last | Homeroom | Grade | Address | Phone | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | Fred | Flinstone | Smith | 2 | 1 Main Street | 555-1212 | Anytown |
| 22 | Barney | Rubble | Jones | 4 | 11 Slate Street | 555-1111 | Bedrock |

In searching, I found and tried the following:

```
import csv #imports module csv

filea = "Original.csv"
fileb = "Updated.csv"
output = "Result.csv"

delim = "," #set your own delimiter

source1 = csv.reader(open(filea,"r"),delimiter=delim)
source2 = csv.reader(open(fileb,"r"),delimiter=delim)
#open csv readers

source2_dict = {}

# prepare changes from file B
for row in source2:
    source2_dict[row[0]] = row[1]

# write new changed rows
with open(output, "w") as fout:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=delim)
    for row in source1:
        # needs to check whether there are any changes prepared
        if row[1] in source2_dict:
            # change the item
            row[3] = source2_dict[row[1]]
        csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

It doesn't work as is and I'm unsure if changing the "row[]" values will make this work.  Whatever numbers I have tried in the various "row[]" areas, I either receive an error or the result file does not contain the desired changes.

Am I on the right path or no?  I would like to match students based on the ID column.

Thank you!

I tried changing the row[] values based on column index with no change to the output file

`row[4] = source2_dict[row[1]]`

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` both DataFrames, remove `homeroom` column from the first DataFrame and all columns expect `Homeroom` in the second DataFrame.

Comment: use a CSVDictReader and Writer instead and this will be much easier.  The way you are putting the items into the source2 dict doesnt make any sense, you are only keeping the 1st element  (first name) as the value.  you want the 3rd element ( Homeroom ) to be saved.  check if row[0] is in source2_dict ( that's the field you used as a key ) not row[1], and then assign it from source2_dict[row[0]]  you are using row[0] as your key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main problems with your solution.  The first is that the intermediate dictionary you are storing as `source_dict2` you are putting the wrong value into its value for the key, you should put the `homeroom` which is `row[3]` NOT `row[1]` which is `first name`.

The second problem is in your lookup and replacement.  Since you were assigning values to the dictionary `source_dict2` by using the `row[0]` or `ID` as the key you need to do a look up on this value, not a lookup on `row[1]` the `first name` because none of them will be a key.   Finally in your replacement you again need to use `row[0]` as the key into the `source_dict2` to get the replacement value.

```
import csv #imports module csv

filea = "Original.csv"
fileb = "Updated.csv"
output = "Result.csv"

delim = "," #set your own delimiter

source1 = csv.reader(open(filea,"r"),delimiter=delim)
source2 = csv.reader(open(fileb,"r"),delimiter=delim)
#open csv readers

source2_dict = {}

# prepare changes from file B
# store the homeroom column
for row in source2:
    source2_dict[row[0]] = row[3]

# write new changed rows
with open(output, "w") as fout:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=delim)
    for row in source1:
        # needs to check whether there are any changes prepared
        # use the key column as the key to search for
        if row[0] in source2_dict:
            # change the item
            row[3] = source2_dict[row[0]] #again use the key column to get the value
        csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest restructuring your code, and especially the process.

I had some trouble reading the code and keeping track of `source1` and `source2` and knowing what *should be happening now, and what happened then?*. This answer hopes to show another way to think about the code and the process.

Namely, I recommend breaking up the process into distinct stages.   The program ends up holding more in memory, but I think it brings some clarity, and allows for debugging any particular stage:

All the code, top-to-bottom:

```py
updates: dict[str, str] = {}
with open("updates.csv", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        updates[row[0]] = row[3]


new_rows: list[list[str]] = []
with open("original.csv", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        row[3] = updates.get(row[0], row[3])
        new_rows.append(row)


with open("output.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(new_rows)
```

If something looks wrong, add a print statement or a break point between any two stages to see what's coming out and going in:

```py
print(updates)
```

Right away we can see that something went wrong gathering the updates:

```py
{"ID": "First", "11": "Fred", "22": "Barney"}
```

Maybe you didn't expect the header to become part the update, but it also helps point out the issue.

```py
...
    for row in reader:
        updates[row[0]] = row[3]
```

```py
{'ID': 'Homeroom', '11': 'Smith', '22': 'Jones'}
```

I usually don't go all-in for "what's *Pythonic*" but using get() with a default value to express that you want to save the update or the original value of the row seems clear:

```py
row[3] = updates.get(row[0], row[3])
```